# MS Access to SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-office

I currently have an accdb file, MS Access file, that has all my existing tables, queries, forms, reports, etc. Years of data are in this file and it has been working well. This access file works with a Forms App that I use on my tablet which does the data collection and writes to this Access file.

Well, now I am looking for a different Forms App but most do not write directly to an accdb file, as far as I can see anyways. Most of the Forms Apps that I have come across say that I can create a read/write link to a SQL Server like MySQL, MS SQL, etc, using an API. I have no idea, really what this means. I looked up API but have very little understanding of this.

What I am wondering now is, is it possible to export my MS Access database onto any of these SQL servers? Everything is set up well, everything is linked together in the MS Access database and I am hoping that I won't have to recreate the entire database because we have to switch to a SQL Server.

Comment: Yes it is possible, in fact many would say preferred to get your data onto a database instead of access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration Access to SQL server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873560/migration-access-to-sql-server-2012)

Comment: There's a built in option for this in MS Access - it's called "Upsizing wizard". It can migrate your data and queries, and I believe it'll offer to change your access front end to point at the database instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the upsizing wizard to move the tables to the SQL server, but all the interface components would remain within Access or the other Forms App that you are already using.

However, I have personally had little luck with the wizard.  If you recreated just the tables, and use queries to move the data when you rebuild them (naming the fields the exact same), you can insert linked tables with the same names and any queries and reports within Access continue to work.

As far as using different Forms Apps and APIs - each will have their advantages, and some will come with completely different programming styles - and you may have to reprogram much of the interface depending on the technology that the forms app uses.